# Spring resource class not able to find a classpath resource

Tags: java, spring, classpath

I have a `data.sql` file located in my `src/main/resources` folder inside my spring boot application. In my source code inside the folder `src/main/java/com/rohitk/app` I have the following code.

```
        try {
            Resource res = new ClassPathResource("classpath:data.sql");
            InputStream stream = res.getInputStream();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

On running this I get an exception stating,

`class path resource [classpath:data.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Giving absolute path also does not help. What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `/data.sql`; remove everything else. Also, make up your mind whether it’s `data.sql` or `input.sql`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ClassPathResource you don't need to enter classpath keyword, pass file name only. And also usually class path means your /src/main/resources directory. try place your data.sql file inside /src/main/resources directory. inside parameter. You can get it like this,

```
Resource res = new ClassPathResource("/data.sql");
```